# exec : hangman.go Executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, path, exit

i have problem trying to run my hangman game (hangman.go) into an other program (server.go)

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("hangman.go")

    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Ive tried to build a hangman.exe too but i still have the same error when i run server.go

```
2021/12/03 10:42:19 exec: "hangman.go": executable file not found in $PATH
exit status 1
```

Comment: You can't "run" hangman.go, that's a source file, not an executable file, it needs to be compiled first.

Comment: "Ive tried to build a hangman.exe too but i still have the same error when i run server.go"     I already did it with a hangman.exe and i have the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. You cannot execute a *.go source file, you must use your compiled `hangman.exe`.
2. If your command "[contains no path separators](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Command)" then `exec.Command()` looks for the command in your `PATH` environment variable, it is not in any of those directories so it is not run. You need to specify a relative or fully qualified path to the file, if it is in the current working directory this can just be `.\hangman.exe` (or `./hangman` on unix like systems):

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command(".\hangman.exe")

    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```